# the meaning of "diffuse strain"

Tags: meaning

*If Benjamin had never written another word about politics after these essays, we would probably understand him today as **a proponent of that diffuse strain of vitalism in early-twentieth century Continental thought** that drew many intellectuals to radical right-wing views and movements after World War I.*

Is it possible to paraphrase the bold passage in this way: *…a proponent of expanding vitalism that was spreading in early-twentieth Continental thought*… The words "diffuse" and "strain" being put together in that clause enable a few interpretations. Do you think that of mine is OK?

Comment: I think you have the general idea but "*expanding* vitalism" is awkward. The word "expanding" is unnecessary in any case since you have "spreading" in the next clause.  **Diffuse** suggests figuratively that it was appearing in various places and was not organized as part of a coherent movement and had no orthodoxy.

Comment: I'm an American native English speaker, and I don't have a clue what "a proponent of that diffuse strain of vitalism in early-twentieth century Continental thought that drew many intellectuals to radical right-wing views and movements after World War I" is supposed to mean. It's terrible writing. No wonder you are confused!